# How to extend sharepoint 2013 web application and provide a different URL's to each extended web applications?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-application, web-application-zones, extended

Can any body tell me how to provide different URL's to the each different extended web applications in different zones (intranet,extranet,default,internet) on SharePoint 2013. Since I am extending one of the SharePoint 2013 webapplication.

Is it necessary to create or provide host header to the web application if we have to extend it.

Or without providing host header to the web application can we extend the SP2013 web application by providing it the different URL?

Answer (score 1):

when you extend a web application, at that you can enter the url. or leave it with server & port numbers.

1. Once the Web app extend, you can go the `Central admin > Application
   managment > Configure the Alternate Access Mapping`.
2. Now on this page, select the web application
3. click on edit the Public URL.
4. Over here you can enter the DNS / URL  what ever you want in the required zone.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2013/05/25/alternate-access-mappings-explained.aspx

Comment: I entered the url, "http://portal.mycompany.com" as told by you in the default zone but after hitting the url it is giving the error "This page can't be displayed" make sure your web address is correct or not. Port numbaer of my site is 5048 & public URL for default zone is "http://sp13dev:5048"

Comment: did you created the DNS record which points to Sharepoint server or it just host file entry? in which zone you extend the web application? also try to access it http://portal.mycompany.com:5048

Comment: No I did'nt created any DNS record that points to the server. And I am extending the web application to intranet zone. What is host file entry?

Comment: if you extend the web app into intranet then why you changing the default zone url...you should change intranet....can you share your AAM setting screen shot.

Comment: My intranet url is "http://sp13dev:19378/" both as internal url & public url for that zone, and after hitting that it is giving me the same error so what should I do so that it will open my web application root level site.

Comment: can you share the screen shot of AAM page.

Comment: sorry sir actually the picture is not loading, I tried a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24716/discussion-between-waqas-sarwar-mcse-and-niranjan-kulkarni).

Comment: Hi Sir, It happened after doing it through sharepoint management powershell.

Comment: And is showing web.config in content view of IIS

Comment: Can you tell me how to extend the web applicaiton for two front end servers. Means the application that I am extending on one front end server is present on another. How can I extend it?